# Increase table border size in bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, border

hello I want to increase border size in this table I try many thing but nothing happen and how make a head table is dark?

Is there any way to solved this issue?

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <br/>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center" width="5%">م</th>
                <th class="text-center" width="40%">{{$receipt_details->table_product_label}}</th>
                <th class="text-center" width="15%">{{$receipt_details->table_qty_label}}</th>
                <th class="text-center" width="20%">{{$receipt_details->table_unit_price_label}}</th>
                <th class="text-center" width="20%">{{$receipt_details->table_subtotal_label}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use CSS, use inline styling. I did it for the `table` and the first `td`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-bordered" style="border-width:4px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center" style="border-width:4px" width="5%">م</th>
      <th class="text-center" width="40%">Front – Multipurpose Responsive Template</th>
      <th class="text-center" width="15%">2</th>
      <th class="text-center" width="20%">$49.00</th>
      <th class="text-center" width="20%">$98.00</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: This is complex.

Answer (score 0):

To make the table header dark, this is from the [Bootstrap 5.3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/content/tables/#table-head) documentation, "Similar to tables and dark tables, use the modifier classes `.table-light` or `.table-dark` to make `<thead>`s appear light or dark gray."

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead class="table-dark">
    ...
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As for the border width, I suggest setting a custom style for your `td` and `th` elements, like this:

```css
td, th {
  border-width: 2px;
}
```